# How to update a Python class object every x amount of time?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

I'm writing a sync script between two project-management programs. I've created a Python class called Project and on initiation, loads data from both programs using python-requests and their respective REST APIs. However, I anticipate that the data will eventually be changed by other users using the programs. Thus, I want to be able to update this Project object at least once every day. How do I do this?

```py
import datetime as dt

class Project(object):
    def __init__(self, project_key):
        self.key = project_key

        self.issues = {}
        self.tasks = {}

        self.__load_tasks()  # loads all tasks into project
        self.__load_issues()  # loads all issues into project

        self.last_updated = dt.datetime.today()
        log.info('Project created on {}'.format(self.last_updated))
```

Comment: On Init start a function with some While infinite loop to do your stuff. Use sleeps at end to control execution (each 60 seconds, each 60 minutes etc)

Comment: @Wonka sleep is blocking. The code would do nothing else but sit and wait to update

Comment: Oh its true, I use thread to dont block it

Comment: @Wonka Could you elaborate on that a bit more? I'm relatively new to python so I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: @vivianyoung I think it would be helpful if you provide more context about your requirements. Do you have some python process that is running continuously on some machine and you would like to do something periodically? Or do you have some script that you need to *run* periodically?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Okay for example, self.__load_issues() makes an API call to JIRA (project management application) using python requests. The JSON response includes a list of issues. I then get each issue and its info in the JSON and pass it into self.issues. However, I know that issues are constantly updated so I want to run self.__load_issues() at least once everyday so that my issues attribute is continuously up to date as the JIRA project is updated online. So, essentially, I want to run a class function periodically. Does that make more sense?

Comment: @vivianyoung that's helpful, you should [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56690411/edit) your question and add that information. But I'm still not sure whether or not you are working with a long-running process, e.g. a server, that has your object in memory continuously, and you need to call that method periodically in this long-running process, or if you have some script/program that runs and terminates, which calls your method and you want to run that program periodically. For the former, you want some thread as implied by Wonka, if the latter, some cron job (or windows equivalent).

Answer (score -2):

If you are n windows you can create a batch file that calls your python script and configure the Windows Task Scheduler to run your batch script every day at a certain hour

your batch file should look like this

```
@echo off
python path\where\your\python\script\is\your_script.py
```

Then create your task in Windows Task Scheduler

Create a basic task and follow the guided process

Hope it helps